# Can I shorten isset() and == in PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement, isset

I was wondering if there is a shorter way to perform this if condition:

```
if(isset($somVar) && $someVar == 'some value')
```

I tried:

```
if($someVar === 'some value')
```

Comment: ...declare `$somVar` beforehand?

Comment: php can handle things just fine without the `isset`, but if you remove it, php will give you a notice, which basically is php's way of telling you "hey, i don't *really* care about this, but thought I should tell you anyway, in case you wanted to be more explicit about things..". Not really a big deal if you have your error reporting turned off for warnings.

Comment: It does only give a notice, not a warning, and notices are usually a good warning sign of typos in variable names. So turning them off in development is a bad thing because you'll hide potential bugs. It is also better to not use nonexistant variables because if you declare them your code becomes easier to read and understand. You don't use some variable out of nothing and nobody can see at once what is in it.

Comment: however, removing it may or may not be okay, depending on what you intend to do with `$somVar`.. for example, if you pass it to some other function that expects a value...

Comment: Does anyone know if you can use the STFU operator `@` with an if( == ) construction?

Answer (score 2):

If you can ensure that `$someVar` is always existing, you can skip the `isset()` part - otherwise you will get a PHP notice if the variable does not exist.

Also note that there is a substantial difference between `==` and `===`.

So I conclude that you cannot shorten that expression.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's not really another 'clean' way, however...

1. You could turn off [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)
2. Alternatively, you could declare your variable in advance

   ```
   $somVar = null;

   // do what you must

   if ($somVar == 'some value') ...
   ```
3. Thirdly, you could [manually suppress](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) error messages *(works in php 5.5)*

   ```
   if (@$someVar == 'some value') ...
   ```

Comment: Nr 2 is useless, as it would overwrite your var. Nr 3 is not true.

Comment: I just tried nr 3 in phpfiddle, and it still gave a warning there. Given, phpfiddle uses php 5.3

Comment: And obviously, nr 2 implies that you set your variable inbetween the declaration and the if structure